# Onfocus conflicting with onmouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Take a look at this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/em3ggdbs/3/

I need the large border around the text input to change color from black to blue, when I hover the mouse over the text input (got this working) and when the text input has focus (with the mouse not hovering on the text input) (**this part is not working**).

```
<div id="border_surrounding_input" style="border:20px solid #000000;padding:20px;">
<input type="text" id="my_text_input">
</div>

document.getElementById("my_text_input").onfocus=function() {
document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#0000ff";

};
document.getElementById("my_text_input").onblur=function() {
document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#000000";

};

document.getElementById("my_text_input").onmouseover=function() {
document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#0000ff";

};


document.getElementById("my_text_input").onmouseout=function() {
document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#000000";

};
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/em3ggdbs/4/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/em3ggdbs/6/

Comment: The clear solution is here https://jsfiddle.net/em3ggdbs/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is when your mouseout or text blur event happen the border color changes without checking is other condition happen or not.

code here:    [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em3ggdbs/5/)

```
    isFocus = false;
isHover = false;

document.getElementById("my_text_input").onfocus=function() {
    isFocus = true;
setBorderColor();
};
document.getElementById("my_text_input").onblur=function() {
    isFocus = false;
    setBorderColor();

};

document.getElementById("my_text_input").onmouseover=function() {
    isHover = true;
    setBorderColor();
};


document.getElementById("my_text_input").onmouseout=function() {
    isHover = false;
    setBorderColor();
};

setBorderColor= function(){
        //isFocus = true;
        if(isFocus || isHover){
            document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#0000ff";
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById("border_surrounding_input").style.borderColor = "#000000";
        }
}
```

Comment: When the input is no longer in focus, the border should turn to black again. It remains stuck on blue.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect solution.